# Flexbox: Why is my item shrinking if I remove display: flex; from my child?

Tags: html, css

I have a code here: https://codepen.io/Elina-Blom/pen/mdvqVKo

I am trying to use flexbox and I want to make the .news section 60 percent in height, and the .card section 40 percent in height. Why do I need to add display: flex; to .content for the 40 vs 60 percent to work? Shouldn't it inherit flex from .section automatically? If I remove this the .news box shrinks to the size of the text in it. I want the box to be 60%. I need to understand this for school.

I am not allowed to use anything else than % for height and width, no pixels.

Respectfully Ellen

removing display: flex;

```
.section {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex; /*Why do I need to add this for the 40 vs 60 percent to work? Shouldn't it inherit flex from .section automatically? If I remove this the .news box shrinks to the size of the text in it. I want the box to be 60%*/
  flex: 0 0 calc(100%/3);
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  background-color: hotpink;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
}

.news {
  background: green;
  color: black;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}
```

Comment: *Shouldn't it inherit flex from .section automatically?* --> No